# Can you have an active launch plan that doesn't have a schedule?

Tags: flyte

And if so, what is the meaning of that? Nothing happens right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, an active launch plan can have no schedule attribute. Any launch plan, regardless of status can be used to trigger a workflow execution.

In Flyte the launch plan status [active|inactive] is only used for determining whether a schedule associated with a launch plan is run.